# need code javascript code for Dynamically created Table - Text value

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript code for Dynamically created Table with one column as Textbox. When I enter vaule in [1row] Text box  it show want to display in form Textbox and also it should want to compare with [2row] Textbox while entering the value. If [2row] Textbox value is greater then [1row] Textbox then Form textbox want to display [2row]  TextBox Value or is should remine.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not clear about what you are exactly looking for. Be specific. Share some code that you have tried. Some use case/ some example will help us more to solve your problem.